# Regex: only matching if character occurs 1 time

Tags: python, regex

I need to create a regex which finds the following pattern:

```
= Head: Some text =
```

I tried this:

```
^(?:[=]).*(?:[=])
```

But it also matches this (which it should not match):

```
== Hello Text 2 ==
```

So how can I tell regex not to match to multiple occurrence of `==`

thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negated character class instead of `.`

```
^=[^=]*=$
```

`[^=]*` is matching any character, but "="

`$` is matching the end of the string

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?34k98)

Comment: Why use `(?:[=])` instead of just `=`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution. Is it possible that you copied the wrong regex? `^(?:[=])[^=]*(?:[=])$`.

Comment: @HotPizzaBox, why? `(?:[=])` is exactly the same than `=`. Not need to put a single character into a character class (and `=` is not a special char), and you also don't need to group a single character using a non capturing group.

Comment: just wrote my post because the regex in your post didn't match the regex you postet at regexr. but it's working for me. thanks

Comment: Ah, I see. Updated the regexr link.

Answer (score 2):

The following is fairly readable:

```
>>> s = '= Head: Some text ='
>>> t = '== Hello Text 2 =='
>>> re.match(r'=[ ](.*?)[ ]=', s).group(1)
'Head: Some text'
>>> re.match(r'=[ ](.*?)[ ]=', t).group(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    re.match(r'=[ ](.*?)[ ]=', t).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Okay, but your regex also matches if the string is `== Hello ==`.

Check here http://regexr.com?34k8a

Comment: @HotPizzaBox not using `re.match` it doesn't... (the link you gave seems to require an explicit `^` at the start of the pattern)